# How to log ONLY chosen inline result article - Python Telegram Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have written a simple script that allows people to write caps texts with my inline bot.

`def inline_caps(bot, update):
    nick=update.inline_query.from_user.username
    query = update.inline_query.query
    try:
        if not query:
            return
        results = list()
        results.append(InlineQueryResultArticle(id=query.upper(),title="Formatta in maiuscolo", input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(query.upper())))
        bot.answerInlineQuery(update.inline_query.id, results)
        log.a((nick)+" ha formattato un testo")
    except Exception as err:
        log.e(err)`

I log everything with a logger made by a friend, you can find it [here](https://github.com/KaikyuDev/KaiDesktop/blob/master/Logger.py).
The problem is that it logs really everything, even if an user only writes "@name_bot t" without choosing to caps it. How can I log ONLY the chosen result?

If you need them, here are my imports:

`from telegram.ext import Updater, Filters, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, InlineQueryHandler, ChosenInlineResultHandler
from telegram import Chat, ParseMode, InlineQueryResultArticle, InputTextMessageContent
import os, math, time, re, random
from time import strftime
from pprint import pprint
import Logger as log
from uuid import uuid4`

And here are my dispatchers:

```
    dp = updater.dispatcher
# Comandi vari:
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help))
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("id", id))
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("groupid", groupid))
# Quindi: dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("comando", funzione))
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("info", info))
# Filtri vari
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, reader))
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.audio, ext_audio))
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.photo, ext_photo))
# Funzionalità inline
inline_caps_handler = InlineQueryHandler(inline_caps)
result_handler = ChosenInlineResultHandler(say_hello)
dp.add_handler(inline_caps_handler)
dp.add_handler(result_handler)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable [inline feedback](https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline#collecting-feedback), and ignore all `inline_query`, obtain query in [chosen_inline_result](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#choseninlineresult).

Comment: But I want to log ONLY chosen inline results. I've already enabled inline feedback and I don't understand what do you mean by ignoring all `inline_query`.

Comment: Don't log `inline_query`, only log `update.chosen_inline_result.query`

Comment: And how can I do it? Should I write "chosen_" in every `update.inline_query.query`?

Comment: I've just written "chosen_" in every `update.inline_query` and the inline_caps doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to log the chosen results, of course you have to do it in the callback function of `result_handler = ChosenInlineResultHandler(say_hello)`, which is your `say_hello` function.

You should be able to log them with [`update.chosen_inline_result`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.choseninlineresult.html#telegram.ChosenInlineResult).